# Sonar scanner running on local but does not work with jenkins pipeline

Tags: java, node.js, jenkins, sonarqube

I want run command on ser sonar-scanner or
sonar-scanner -Dsonar.projectKey=node-myapp -Dsonar.sources=. -Dsonar.host.url=http://ip:9000 -Dsonar.login=key

I am trying with run .sh file in pipeline or direct scan from pipeline
working on file but not work form jenkins pipeline and got error:

Error:sonar-scanner.sh: 4: sonar-scanner: not found

also
ERROR: script returned exit code 127
[image]

Comment: Check what does that script returns, put "echo $?" immediately after the sonar-scanner.sh

Comment: The error is because Jenkins is not able to find the path of sonar scanner. You can set the path of sonar-scanner in Global Tools configuration.